# Can we use Get instead of Navigator 2.0 for route management in flutter?

Tags: flutter-navigation, flutter-getx

I had seen few videos about flutter navigator 2.0 ..
and found it is very difficult to understand and implement.. so my question is can we use Get instead of navigator 2.0 for complex project also...??

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer for that:
https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/1220

However this library is not mentioned in this topic that flutter team want's to choose corrrect library to handle Navigator 2.0:
https://github.com/flutter/uxr/issues/10